# Change value of request.remote_ip in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

For test purposes I want to change the return value of request.remote_ip. While being on my development machine it returns always 127.0.0.1 as it should but I would like to give myself different fake IPs to test the correct behavior of my app without deploying it to an live server first!

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want this functionality in your whole application, it might be better/easier to override the remote_ip method in your `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
class ActionDispatch::Request #rails 2: ActionController::Request
  def remote_ip
    '1.2.3.4'
  end
end
```

And the 1.2.3.4 address is available everywhere

Answer (score 6):

For integration tests, this works with rails 5:

```
get "/path", params: { }, headers: { "REMOTE_ADDR" => "1.2.3.4" }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the request object using:

```
request = ActionController::Request.new('REMOTE_ADDR' => '1.2.3.4')
```

`request.remote_ip` now returns 1.2.3.4

Comment: this makes the request with the new IP only available for the current scope. I need a way to change it for the whole application.

Comment: You are right, I added a new answer to enable it for your whole application

Answer (score 5):

You can cheat a bit by making a mutator for the remote_ip value in the test environment which is normally not defined.

For instance, alter the class inside of test/test_helper.rb with the following:

```
class ActionController::TestRequest
  def remote_ip=(value)
    @env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = value.to_s
  end
end
```

Then, during your testing you can reassign as required:

```
def test_something
  @request.remote_ip = '1.2.3.4'
end
```

This can be done either in the individual test, or within your setup routine, wherever is appropriate.

I have had to use this before when writing functional tests that verify IP banning, geolocation, etc.

Comment: this goes more in the direction I want to go in. But I want to make this available for development environment/manuel testing. Is there some place I could put @env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = "1.2.3.4"?

Answer (score 5):

rails 4.0.1 rc. After hour of searching found this simple solution while digging to code :)

```
get '/', {}, { 'REMOTE_ADDR' => '1.2.3.4' }
```

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing now was to put this code in the end of the `config/environments/development.rb` file to make sure it's only executed while in development

```
# fake IP for manuel testing
class ActionController::Request
  def remote_ip
    "1.2.3.4"
  end
end
```

So this sets remote_ip to 1.2.3.4 when the server starts. Everytime you change the value you have to restart the server!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only works for rails3 (I found this answer when trying to answer a similar question for rails 3),

So I will post it here in case if someone is trying to do the same thing in Rails3 env

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
  def remote_ip
    '1.2.3.4'
  end
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails7 with Rspec, I was able to change the value of `request.remote_ip` to return `1.2.3.4` by adding the following `before` section to my test request:

```rb
  before :each do
    allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:remote_addr).and_return('1.2.3.4')
  end
```

To see this more in context, the whole request becomes:

```rb
RSpec.describe "Foos", type: :request do
  before :each do
    allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:remote_addr).and_return('1.2.3.4')
  end
  describe "GET /status" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get "/foo/status"
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

Then, inside of my `Foo` controllers `status` method, `request.remote_ip` returns whatever value assigned in the test.