# Specify host for Rails functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Some of my controller actions use the request.host parameter in their logic. In integration tests I can use the `host!` method to set the host. How can the same be achieved in functional tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found my own solution:

```
def setup
  @request.host = 'test.example.com'
end
```

The @request object is reused between requests, so it only has to be set once.

Comment: For more information about manipulating the request variable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029488/change-value-of-request-remoteip-in-ruby-on-rails/ where the only difference is that the remote_ip was modified instead of host