# Fake IP for geocoder in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip-address, development-environment, rails-geocoder

I want to replace the 127.0.0.1 IP that I have in the development environment in order to test manually the geocoder gem. How can I do that ?

I tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115589/geocoder-how-to-test-locally-when-ip-is-127-0-0-1), but it doesn't work. I meet the following error :

```rb
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/infle‌​ctor/methods.rb:226:in 'const_get': uninitialized constant SpoofIp (NameError)
```

Comment: Below stackoverflow post has a similar question and a good answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115589/geocoder-how-to-test-locally-when-ip-is-127-0-0-1

Comment: Yes, but it didn't worked for me. Perhaps there is another way to do it ?

Comment: How about overriding the  requst.remote_ip method in Dev environment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029488/change-value-of-request-remote-ip-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Ok, but how can you do that, only in dev environment ?

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

My answer not for everyone since I wanted to test `request.location` locally only. But if you want to do the same then I have the solution for you. First of all, let me show you source code for `.location` method:

```
module Geocoder
  module Request

    def location
      @location ||= begin
        detected_ip = env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] || (
          env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] &&
          env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].split(",").first.strip
        )
        detected_ip = IpAddress.new(detected_ip.to_s)
        if detected_ip.valid? and !detected_ip.loopback?
          real_ip = detected_ip.to_s
        else
          real_ip = self.ip
        end
        Geocoder.search(real_ip).first
      end
      @location
    end
  end
end

# ...
```

As you can see, there is variable `detected_ip` and to find it's data gem checks out `env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']`. Well, now we can easily stub that in our controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController    
  def index
    env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] = '1.2.3.4' if Rails.env.development?
    location = request.location

    # => #<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x007fe695394da0 @data={"ip"=>"1.2.3.4", "country_code"=>"AU", "country_name"=>"Australia", "region_code"=>"", "region_name"=>"", "city"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "latitude"=>-27, "longitude"=>133, "metro_code"=>"", "area_code"=>""}, @cache_hit=nil> 
  end
end
```

It works with geocoder '1.2.5' (can't promise that it works with earlier versions - you need check out source code for that or bump the gem).

Comment: So good, thanks a lot! I'd put that `env[HTTP_X_REAL_IP]` in a before_filter in `ApplicationController` of course use it only in development.

Comment: Geocoder 1.2.6 [has changed](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/c1010e629a4676c1b300ea26805ab0a7991edf9b/lib/geocoder/request.rb#L62). Use `env['REMOTE_ADDR']` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct answer:

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
  def remote_ip
    "1.2.3.4"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your config/environments/development.rb.

```
class ActionController::Request
  def remote_ip
    "1.2.3.4"
  end
end
```

Restart your server.

Comment: Thanks ! But why `ActionController` and not `ActionDispatch` ?

Comment: It doesn't work :-( If I do something like `<h3>Current Location : </h3><%= request.location.city %>`, the page renders only `<h3>Current Location : </h3>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated answer for geocoder 1.2.9 to provide a hardcoded IP for development and test environments:

```
if %w(development test).include? Rails.env
  module Geocoder
    module Request
      def geocoder_spoofable_ip_with_localhost_override
        ip_candidate = geocoder_spoofable_ip_without_localhost_override
        if ip_candidate == '127.0.0.1'
          '1.2.3.4'
        else
          ip_candidate
        end
      end
      alias_method_chain :geocoder_spoofable_ip, :localhost_override
    end
  end
end
```